# Purpose of get set in an Apex Class used in a trigger?

Tags: apex

I am simply trying to get my head around what is the purpose of get set in cases other than Visualforce page controllers.

What is the point of having for example this:

```
Set<Id> ids {get; set;}
```

or this:

```
Map<String, String> map1 {get; set;}
```

If I am later going to use ids.add(arg0) function or map1.put(arg0, arg1) functions? Is get set a redundant thing in case of Apex triggers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no point in using `{ get; set; }` specifically, except for Visualforce and `@AuraEnabled` properties (Lightning). The main purpose for these are when you want to do something special.

Getters and setters can be used to implement lazy-loading, read-only or write-only properties, validation of values, and so on. The `get;` and `set;` provide default functionality. If you omit them, you make the property write-only or read-only:

```
readOnlyField { get; }
writeOnlyField { set; }
```

You can also apply access modifiers, typically to make a field read-only or write only outside of the current class:

```
readOnlyField { get; private set; }
writeOnlyField { private get; set; }
```

Here's other things you can do:

```
Integer counter { 
  get { 
    if(counter == null) {
      counter = 0; 
    }
    return counter++; 
  } 
  private set;
}
```

Which lets you:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.debug(counter); // We'll output 0 through 9.
}
```

You can do "lazy loading":

```
public Account defaultAccount { 
  get { 
    if(defaultAccount == null) { 
      defaultAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsDefault__c = true]; 
    }
    return defaultAccount; 
  } 
  private set;
}
```

You can implement validation:

```
public Integer age {
  get; 
  set {
    if(value > 0) {
      age = value;
    } else {
      age = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, there are a lot of uses for getters and setters. Do you want to use it inside your trigger? Probably not. Will you find a use for them eventually? Possibly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Question was downvoted, as I assumed it would be, yet you still answered! :)